# How can i get the absolute position of an UISlider inside of a View

Tags: swift, uislider

i have created a subview with a lot sliders in it

```
var sliderArea = UIView()

sliderArea = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 300, y: 400, width: 500, height: 100)
view.addSubview(sliderArea)

mySlider1 = setUpSlider(sliderNr: 1, ypos: 30)
mySlider2 = setUpSlider(sliderNr: 2, ypos: 30)
mySlider3 = setUpSlider(sliderNr: 3, ypos: 30)

sliderArea.addSubview(mySlider1)
sliderArea.addSubview(mySlider2)
sliderArea.addSubview(mySlider3)
```

i have a lot of subviews similar to the "sliderArea" to be able to change my sliders quickly while the layout adopts automatically
now i need to know where the absolute position of each slider is to place buttons on top of it. i need to have all this buttons inside an extra view on top of it all. any ideas? thank you

Comment: Why not use auto layout?

Comment: great idea. but i still need to know how to get the absolute position

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your **slider** frame to `window`'s coordinate system using this method of CGRect:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622504-convert

Just pass **nil** as second parameter and it will return you an absolute frame.

Comment: thanks. i have tried it: let pos = slider.convert(slider.frame, to: nil) but it just gives me the position inside the sliderArea. i need the position on the screen. :-/ @igor